# How to get the user full name in BPM 7.5 by using tw.system.org?

Tags: ibm-bpm

I am currently working with IBM BPM 7.5. I am unable to get the user's fullname by using the tw.system.org. How to get the user full name in BPM 7.5 by using tw.system.org?

Answer (score 1):

**tw.system.user_fullname** should be returning the full name of the user.

I had a V8 with me and did a quick check and i did see this response

[31/05/12 11:17:32:371 EST] 0000004e wle_javascrip I   FUll User name is:Administrator

Comment: yeah i am currently working with 7.5.0.1  and I am not using LDAP i want the full name from Process Admin

Comment: I have given you the answer there. Not sure what else are you looking for! I have edited the response keeping the answer in bold. It does not really matter what you use as your user registry (that is under the hood and you don't need to worry about using one API for LDAP and one for database users etc).

Answer (score 1):

For the full name in IBM BPM (and WLE), you need a few fixes for BPM and Websphere. Specifically on the WAS version you are on (WAS v7).

See this reference for details: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21570176

Essentially, you need these WAS fixes: `PM37925` and `PM18594` which are in WAS 7.0.0.21 and later.
You will also need to adjust the `wimconfig.xml` as noted in the referenced link.

In later versions (8.0.1) take a look at this IBM dwAnswer article titled "L[DAP User Full Name Sync](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/170380/bpm-801-ldap-user-full-name-sync/?smartspace=bpm)" and for 8.5.x "[Incorrect displaying of users full name](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/187102/incorrect-displaying-of-users-full-name-when-you-u/?smartspace=bpm)"

Comment: This looks like the start of a good answer to this question.  It seems like you may have forgotten to include another article you referenced for V8.  Also, try and include more details about how to solve the problem in your answer directly instead of "do what the article says".  Links go dead all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Process Designer , write in scripts for test

Define for example private variable FullName.

tw.local.tw.system.user_fullname;